# Tag for intravenous (IV)

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

At the moment, we have tag [iv-intravaneous](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iv-intravaneous), which is problematic for two reasons:

1. [Again](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1203/12704), a synonym is included in the tag name, rather than as a tag synonym.
2. It misspells "intravenous".

Hence, I propose that the tag be renamed [intravenous](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intravenous) with synonym [iv](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iv).

Comment: I think it's great you're going through tags and cleaning them up. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I implemented your proposal, but like the [previous](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1205/805) edit the *iv* synonym still needs to be approved.